# Lightweight JS Library vs Google-hosted CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, google-cdn

When page-load speed is the priority, is it better to use a minimal, lightweight javascript library (hosted on a CDN), or is it better to use something like jQuery, hosted on Google's CDN that the browser more than likely already has loaded?

Edit: What my question really boils down to is whether the cross-site caching effect of using jQuery hosted on Google's CDN outweighs the benefits of using an ultra-light library, also on a CDN.

Comment: Either way it is only loaded maximum once.

Comment: I always find the concern about loading 95 KB of jQuery quite odd considering that many of these sites already contain several hundred KB's of un-optimized graphics and most users are on high speed connections.  A high number of simultaneous jQuery animations is far more tangibly detrimental to the user experience than initial page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is not heavy as compared to any other javascript library at present looking at the amount of features and browsers it supports.

You can consider this factor while selecting the plugins to be used on the page because they are written by various users and some may right it intelligently considering this factor or some may just right it for the sake.

Yes, if you use CDN like Google for jQuery it is most likely that the library must be cached by the browser and also Google has number of servers based on location so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: regarding the "goole loactions" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943588/is-google-web-fonts-or-cdn-bad

Answer (score 1):

**Decreased Latency**

A CDN distributes your static content across servers in various, diverse physical locations. When a user’s browser resolves the URL for these files, their download will automatically target the closest available server in the network.

In the case of Google’s AJAX Libraries CDN, what this means is that any users not physically near your server will be able to download jQuery faster than if you force them to download it from your arbitrarily located server.
There are a handful of CDN services comparable to Google’s, but it’s hard to beat the price of free! This benefit alone could decide the issue, but there’s even more.

**Increased parallelism**

To avoid needlessly overloading servers, browsers limit the number of connections that can be made simultaneously. Depending on which browser, this limit may be as low as two connections per hostname.
Using the Google AJAX Libraries CDN eliminates one request to your site, allowing more of your local content to downloaded in parallel. It doesn’t make a gigantic difference for users with a six concurrent connection browser, but for those still running a browser that only allows two, the difference is noticeable.

**Better caching**

Potentially the greatest benefit of using the Google AJAX Libraries CDN is that your users may not need to download jQuery at all.
No matter how well optimized your site is, if you’re hosting jQuery locally then your users must download it at least once. Each of your users probably already has dozens of identical copies of jQuery in their browser’s cache, but those copies of jQuery are ignored when they visit your site.

However, when a browser sees references to CDN-hosted copies of jQuery, it understands that all of those references do refer to the exact same file. With all of these CDN references point to exactly the same URLs, the browser can trust that those files truly are identical and won't waste time re-requesting the file if it's already cached. Thus, the browser is able to use a single copy that's cached on-disk, regardless of which site the CDN references appear on.

This creates a potent "cross-site caching" effect which all sites using the CDN benefit from. Since Google's CDN serves the file with headers that attempt to cache the file for up to one year, this effect truly has amazing potential. With many thousands of the most trafficked sites on the Internet already using the Google CDN to serve jQuery, it's quite possible that many of your users will never make a single HTTP request for jQuery when they visit sites using the CDN.
Even if someone visits hundreds of sites using the same Google hosted version of jQuery, they will only need download it once!

Comment: The question wasn't really about what a CDN is, or what the benefits are.

Comment: @kennis: After reading it again, probably not. It was the title of the question that made me submit this. "Lightweight JS Library vs Google-hosted CDN", I assumed the light weight JS library was hosted locally, and he wanted to know what the benefits were for local and CDN. This may help him a little if he choose a CDN hosted library

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely useful. What I'm really wondering though is if the cross-site caching effect of using jQuery on Google's CDN outweighs the benefits of using an ultra-light library, also on a CDN.

Comment: Interesting question. I believe an ultra-light, CDN hosted library will load faster than the jQuery library, but not by a huge amount. Personally, I would chose a minified jQuery CDN as it becomes more and more popular by the day. The chances of your visitor having already downloaded it at some point, is quite high.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the library that best suits the needs of your application and your development team. A super-lightweight library might save you a few hundred milliseconds of load time, but may end up costing you in development hours if your team has significantly more experience with jQuery/MooTools/Dojo etc.

If new feature implementation and bug fixing is hindered by using a second-rate tool solely to improve load times, your users are ultimately going to suffer.