# Contact form 7 seems not to work with foundation. No console errors though

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Link is there:
http://lavii.ee/proov
Contact form isnt working properly.

As contact form 7 refers- it seems to be [ajax error](http://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/). Cant figure out what exactly is wrong there...

Comment: There is nothing wrong I can see there . It is working ok , confirmation and all. It is just quite slow .

Comment: Actually its not. There are two things- 
1) It adds #wpcf7-f4-p2-o1 into the website url end
2) It refreshes the page (it shouldnt)
And a third one 
3) When i try to use the following link which is supposed to redirect the page,  it wont work.
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';" Oh, and there is no spinning arrows if we compare it to [this](http://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/)

Comment: Dude.. Next time , please do elaborate a bit . just saying "not working" is not enough.. People here can not guess what is wrong. Please add the code ( form fields from wpcf7 ) or something more to work with ... For end users just submitting the form works .

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can cause the errors you have described ( in the comments ) above.

one of them is the missing `wp_footer()` , `wp_header()` functions in header and footer respectively , but if you did not manually removed them , they are included in foundation.

Another reason is  wrong loading of js /jQuery. which is probably the case with your theme since indeed it seems the wpcf7 script is not loading ..

The wp-foundation theme is actually using a very bad practice of deregistring wp own jQuery and loading a "personal" version.

I can not even start to enumerate the reasons [why it is wrong](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) .

While not 100% sure , It is probably one of the reasons ( if not THE reason )

the code is in functions.php

```
/************* ENQUEUE JS *************************/

/* pull jquery from google's CDN. If it's not available, grab the local copy. Code from wp.tutsplus.com :-) */

$url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'; // the URL to check against  
$test_url = @fopen($url,'r'); // test parameters  
if( $test_url !== false ) { // test if the URL exists  

    function load_external_jQuery() { // load external file  
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'); // register the external file  
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // enqueue the external file  
    }  

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_external_jQuery'); // initiate the function  
} else {  

    function load_local_jQuery() {  
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // initiate the function  
        wp_register_script('jquery', bloginfo('template_url').'/javascripts/jquery.min.js', __FILE__, false, '1.7.2', true); // register the local file  
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // enqueue the local file  
    }  

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_local_jQuery'); // initiate the function  
}
```

The right code should simply be

```
   function load_local_jQuery() {  

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // enqueue the local file  
    }  

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_local_jQuery'); // initiate the function
```

to load wp own jQuery ...

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943588/is-google-web-fonts-or-cdn-bad/19969239#19969239) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go?rq=1)

Also, disable all other plugins when testing and make sure you use the latest release for both wpcf7 and wp itself ...